# Is $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\dots$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let  $a_n= (-1)^k$ ,when $2^k \leq n < 2^{k+1} $.
>
> ### Then determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converge or not.

[my attempt]

I try to apply Dirichlet tset but I fail.
So I tried following method

$$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\dots \geq  1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{8}-\dots = 1 - 1 +1 + \dots $$ However this has no information so I fail,too

May I ask you how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Hint: $1/2 + 1/3 > 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2$, and $1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 > 1/8 + 1/8  + 1/8 + 1/8 = 1/2$. This pattern continues. What does this imply about the sequence of partial sums?

Comment: Expanding my hint slightly in response to the edit. If $S_n$ denotes the $n$'th partial sum, consider the subsequence $S_1, S_3, S_7, S_{15},\ldots$, i.e. the subsequence $S_{2^{n}-1}$. What can you say about the differences between adjacent terms of this subsequence? Does this subsequence converge?

Answer (score 2):

Bunching terms with the same sign together already gives you enough information. Each such bunched term has a magnitude of at least $\frac12$, which means that the series diverges by Cauchy's test (all sums of sufficiently far sequences of arbitrary length must be less than any $\varepsilon$ for the series to converge).

Comment: (+1) The bunched terms sum to approximately $\log(2)$, but otherwise this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

With $S(m)=\sum_{j=1}^m(a_j/j)$ we have $$|S(2^{m+1}-1)-S(2^m-1)|=\sum_{j=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}(1/j)> \sum_{j=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}(1/2^{m+1})=2^m(1/2^{m+1})=1/2$$ for every $m\in \Bbb N.$

If $S(m)$ converged to $L\in \Bbb R$ then $S(2^m-1)$ would also converge to $L,$ which is impossible because consecutive terms of the sequence $(\,S(2^m-1)\,)_{m\in \Bbb N}$ differ (in absolute value) from each other by more than $1/2.$